# How to calculate maximum flow in a directed graph that contains cycles

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, network-flow

I'm trying to find maximum flow in a network using `Ford Fulkerson` algorithm, it works great for acyclic graphs however if there's a cycle it'd loop forever. Here's the code I'm using to find the max flow:

```
class Edge (object):
    reverse = None
    def __init__ (self, u, v, w):
        self.source = u
        self.sink = v  
        self.capacity = w
        self.flow = 0

class FlowNetwork (object):
    def __init__ (self, path):
        rows = len (path)
        cols = len (path[0])
        self.graph = {self.vname (x, rows): [] for x in range (rows)}
        for r in range (rows):
            for c in range (cols):
                if path[r][c] > 0:
                    u = self.vname (r, rows)
                    v = self.vname (c, rows)
                    edge = Edge (u, v, path[r][c])
                    reverse = Edge (v, u, 0)
                    edge.reverse = reverse
                    reverse.reverse = edge
                    self.graph[u].append (edge)
                    self.graph[v].append (reverse)

    def vname (self, x, t):
        return 's' if x == 0 else 't' if x == t - 1 else 'v' + str (x)

    def dfs (self, source, sink):
        queue = [[x] for x in self.graph[source]]
        while queue:
            path = queue.pop (0)
            vertex = path[-1]
            if vertex.sink == sink: return path
            for edge in self.graph[vertex.sink]:
                if edge.capacity - edge.flow > 0:
                    if edge not in path and edge.reverse not in path:
                        queue.append ([x for x in path] + [edge])

    def maxFlow (self, source, sink):
        path = self.dfs (source, sink)
        while path != None:
            flow = min ([edge.capacity - edge.flow for edge in path])
            for edge in path:
                edge.flow += flow
                edge.reverse.flow -= flow
            path = self.dfs (source, sink)
        return sum (edge.flow for edge in self.graph[source])
```

For example if I use the above program to solve the following network:

[image: graph with a cycle]

It will run indefinitely, how do I find the maximum flow in such networks?

## Update:

I forgot to keep track of visited edges in the depth first search dfs function in the code above, so I fixed it like so:

```
def dfs (self, source, sink):
    queue = [[x] for x in self.graph[source]]
    visited = []
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop (0)
        vertex = path[-1]
        if vertex.sink == sink: return path
        for edge in self.graph[vertex.sink]:
            if edge not in visited and edge.capacity - edge.flow > 0:
                if edge not in path and edge.reverse not in path:
                    queue.append ([x for x in path] + [edge])
                    visited.append (edge)
```

However it's still looping indefinitely.

Comment: I haven't studied your code in detail, but off hand it looks like your DFS isn't a proper DFS. It needs an "already visited set" to avoid cycles. You should look at a variant of FF (like Edmons-Karp) that details the method used to find augmenting paths.

Comment: @Gene I fixed dfs function but It's still looping forever on reverse edge (s, t) for some reason, why is that?

Comment: Maybe it's that you're not accounting for reverse edges visited list? Also note to avoid increasing asymptotic run time, you should use a real set for visited, not a list.

Comment: The visited set should contain vertices, not edges. In general, you code looks pretty strange as their is no clear distinction between edges and vertices (there should be). It's probably the source of the bug.